# How should I group several radio inputs?

Tags: html, radio-button, forms, radio-group

When in a form I have several radio inputs that make a single control (example below), what's the most semantic way to group them together?

```
<form>
  <!-- Single radio control made of 3 radio inputs -->
  <input type="radio" name="X" value="A" />
  <input type="radio" name="X" value="B" />
  <input type="radio" name="X" value="C" />

  <!-- Some other control -->
  <input type="text" name="Y" value="D" />
</form>
```

I know I can enclose them in a paragraph (`<p>..</p>`), but I wonder if maybe list (`<ul>..</ul>`) would be more semantic approach?

Comment: use a [fieldset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset): The HTML `<fieldset>` element is used to group several controls as well as labels (`<label>`) within a web form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group together by using **fieldset**

```css
.radio_button{
  list-style-type: none;
  }
```

```html
<form>
  <h1>Testing Form Radio buttons</h1>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Title</legend>
      <ul>
        <li class="radio_button">
          <label for="title_1">
            <input type="radio" id="title_1" name="title" value="M." />
            Mister
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="radio_button">
          <label for="title_2">
            <input type="radio" id="title_2" name="title" value="Ms." />
            Miss
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </fieldset>
    </section>
    
   </form>
```

Comment: By using List is the good approach to enclose the radio buttons

Comment: Why use both fieldset and list? What are benefits to this in comparison to use fieldset-only or list-only approach?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form>
<!-- Single radio control made of 3 radio inputs -->
<ul>
<li>
  <input type="radio" name="X" value="A" />A
</li>
<li>
  <input type="radio" name="X" value="B" />B
</li>
<li>
  <input type="radio" name="X" value="C" />C
</li>
</ul>
  <input type="text" name="Y" value="D" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way would be using the bootstrap lib and format your forms with bootstrap
 : [Bootstrap form inputs](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_inputs.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the name field same if you want to get only 1 value selected,
And only selected field's value (value = "A") will be submitted.

You can group them using css styles. **W3.css** is a nice library like bootstrap.
[W3.css examples](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_input.asp)